# C++17 using std::variant to represent DOM

Tags: c++, dom, c++17, variant

I'm trying to learn how to use`std::variant` from C++17. As an example started using it, to represent the DOM. Though this is still work in progress:

1. I wanted to get expert opinion on the usage of `std::variant`
2. also some inputs on the compiler support.

I've the `DOM representation code` ([Godbolt's Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/)) and it seems to compile fine with [`Clang trunk`](https://godbolt.org/g/qKVGnx). However, I see that the same code does not compile with [`GCC 8.0.0 20171009`](https://godbolt.org/g/tFLW16).

I would like to understand what is the reason for this incompatibility. And also if anyone can comment on the "style" and if this is an appropriate usage of `std::variant`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <unordered_map>

// https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ : reference for the DOM.

namespace dragon {
    namespace dom {
        namespace traits_ns {
            template <bool valid_node_type = false>
            struct valid_node {
                static constexpr bool value = valid_node_type;
            };

            template <typename T>
            struct is_valid_node {
                static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of<valid_node<true>, T>::value && T::value;
            };

            // TODO: Need to define policy concepts which will check if the children 
            // of each node is of the right, allowed type.
        }

        struct Element;
        struct Text;
        struct Document;
        struct Document_type;
        struct Document_fragment;
        struct Processing_instruction;
        struct Comment;

        using AttrList = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
        using AttrSet = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
        using Node = std::variant<Document, Document_type, Document_fragment, Element, Text, Processing_instruction, Comment>;
        using Children = std::vector<Node>;


        struct Element final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            Element(std::string t, const Children& c, const AttrList& a) : tag{ t }, child{ c } {}
            Element() = default;
            ~Element() = default;
            std::string tag;
            Children child;
            AttrSet attr;
        };

        struct Text final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            explicit Text(std::string d) : data{ d } {}
            std::string data;
        };

        struct Document final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            Document() = default;
            ~Document() = default;
        };

        struct Document_type final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Document_fragment final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Processing_instruction final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Comment final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};

    } // namespace dom
} // namespace dragon


namespace dom = dragon::dom;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    dom::Node t{dom::Text{"Hello"}};
    dom::Node e{dom::Element{"element", {}, {{"class", "blah"}}}};
    return 0;
}
```

Snippet of errors Produced by GCC:

```
        #1 with x86-64 gcc (trunk)

    In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/move.h:55:0,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/vector:60,
                     from <source>:1:
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::is_trivially_destructible<dragon::dom::Document>':
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/type_traits:2859:25:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_destructible_v<dragon::dom::Document>'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:309:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>::_S_trivial_dtor'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:317:20:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>::_S_trivial_move_assign'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:642:16:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Move_assign_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_move_assign, _Types ...> [with _Types = {dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment}]'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:645:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:1032:11:   required from 'class std::variant<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>'
    41 : <source>:41:86:   required from here
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/type_traits:1285:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct dragon::dom::Document'
         struct is_trivially_destructible
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    28 : <source>:28:10: note: forward declaration of 'struct dragon::dom::Document'
       struct Document;
              ^~~~~~~~
    In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/move.h:55:0,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                     from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/vector:60,
                     from <source>:1:
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_destructible_v<dragon::dom::Document>':
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:309:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>::_S_trivial_dtor'
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:317:20:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>::_S_trivial_move_assign'

<SNIP> 

dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment}]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
           variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;
           ^~~~~~~
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:1087:7: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr std::_Enable_copy_move<false, false, false, false, _Tag>::_Enable_copy_move(const std::_Enable_copy_move<false, false, false, false, _Tag>&) [with _Tag = std::variant<dragon::dom::Document, dragon::dom::Document_type, dragon::dom::Document_fragment, dragon::dom::Element, dragon::dom::Text, dragon::dom::Processing_instruction, dragon::dom::Comment>]'
    In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/variant:38:0,
                     from <source>:4:
    /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20171009/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/enable_special_members.h:301:15: note: declared here
         constexpr _Enable_copy_move(_Enable_copy_move const&) noexcept  = delete;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Compiler exited with result code 1

        x86-64 gcc (trunk) (Editor #1, Compiler #1)

    g++ (GCC-Explorer-Build) 8.0.0 20171009 (experimental)- cached
```

Comment: Hello, it seems your question has two parts: (1) why doesn't the code compile, (2) is this good code? The second part should be posted to codereview.stackexchange.com. For the first part, please provide a *minimal* example sufficient to reproduce the GCC compile error.

Comment: @Brian thanks Brian, will post to code review. For the compiler error, the link provided should give the errors as-well. Please let me know if it doesn’t show up. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide a version of your code that is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here

Comment: @Brian that is my version of the code. I’ve given the link compiler explorer generated for my code. Not sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, as plain text. A "link provided", that can stop working at any time in future, rendering the question meaningless, is insufficient. Unless you edit the question and provide a [mcve] in the question itself, it will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik & @ Brian: makes sense. I apologize. updated the question with the code and snippet of the errors GCC seems to produce. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element's constructor depends on the type Node, which depends on the other node types.

At the point of the definition of the constructor, these other node types are not complete types (they are defined below).

#### Solution:

move the body of the constructor below the node type definitions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <unordered_map>

// https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ : reference for the DOM.

namespace dragon {
    namespace dom {
        namespace traits_ns {
            template <bool valid_node_type = false>
            struct valid_node {
                static constexpr bool value = valid_node_type;
            };

            template <typename T>
            struct is_valid_node {
                static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of<valid_node<true>, T>::value && T::value;
            };

            // TODO: Need to define policy concepts which will check if the children 
            // of each node is of the right, allowed type.
        }

        struct Element;
        struct Text;
        struct Document;
        struct Document_type;
        struct Document_fragment;
        struct Processing_instruction;
        struct Comment;

        using AttrList = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
        using AttrSet = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
        using Node = std::variant<Document, Document_type, Document_fragment, Element, Text, Processing_instruction, Comment>;
        using Children = std::vector<Node>;


        struct Element final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            Element(std::string t, const Children& c, const AttrList& a);
            Element() = default;
            ~Element() = default;
            std::string tag;
            Children child;
            AttrSet attr;
        };

        struct Text final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            explicit Text(std::string d) : data{ d } {}
            std::string data;
        };

        struct Document final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {
            Document() = default;
            ~Document() = default;
        };

        struct Document_type final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Document_fragment final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Processing_instruction final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};
        struct Comment final : traits_ns::valid_node<true> {};

        Element::Element(std::string t, const Children& c, const AttrList& a) : tag{ t }, child{ c } {}

    } // namespace dom
} // namespace dragon


namespace dom = dragon::dom;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    dom::Node t{dom::Text{"Hello"}};
    dom::Node e{dom::Element{"element", {}, {{"class", "blah"}}}};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! Just curious why clang did not complain about it! GCC and Visual Studio seem to not like it.. is there a behavior defined in the standard?

Comment: @user3169543 clang has a legendary permissiveness all of its own. I work in an environment where we use clang, gcc and MSVC. We always compile on gcc to find the subtle errors that the other compilers miss.

Comment: @user3169543 the next problem you will hit is that `std::variant` does not support recursion (boost has recursive_wrapper). My strong suggestion for a tree-like structure would be to dump the `std::variant` and use boost. Otherwise you'll end up writing your own cloneable wrapper types, which is just a case of reinventing a perfectly good (and tested!) wheel.